# How to get firebase unique key in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am inserting an object of type WhatsappElement class

```
class WhatsappElements
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
WhatsappElements newwhatsapp = new WhatsappElements
  {
        Number = txt_number.Text+"&N",
        Message = txt_message.Text+"&M",
   };
   await client.PushAsync("WhatsappElements/Data" , newwhatsapp);
```

The data shows as follows

```
  -Data
```

-NBSUSIOSPPSWEIE

in the other app which I try to retrieve I use the following code

```
public async void getdAta()
    {
        var resp = await server.GetAsync("WhatsappElements/Data");
        WhatsappElements element = resp.ResultAs<WhatsappElements>();
        MessageBox.Show(element.Number);
        
    }
```

But it prints a blank , what am i doing wrong? or how can I get the data ? or even return the unique key?

Answer (score 0):

Since you write the data with `PushAsync`, the database creates a new child node under `Data` with a unique key. When you read the value from `Data`, you have to cater for that key by iterating over the child nodes of the result.

You'll want to get the result as a `Dictionary` and then loop over entries or values in that dictionary.